# How to to over-ride the height of my footer using Bootstrap v3 Twitter

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I want to over-ride the height of my footer using Bootstrap v3 Twitter.

I have placed the over ride in the style.  This is what i have tried:

```
.navbar .my-footer
{
    height:20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="navbar navbar-inverse my-footer navbar-fixed-bottom" style="height: 20px">
    <div class="container-fluid" style="background-color: #66FF66; height: 20px">
        <div id="lblMessage" class="navbar-text" style="color: #FFFFFF; font-weight: bold;
                margin-left: 5px; font-size: smaller; height: 20px">
        </div>
        <div id="lblConnectionStatus" class="navbar-text text-right" style="color: #FFFFCC;
                font-weight: bold; margin-left: 5px; text-align: right; width: 100%; font-size: smaller;
                float: left; display: none; height: 20px">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: It would be `.navbar.my-footer` (no space). However this would be ineffective anyway because inline styles take precedence (without the use of `!important`).

Comment: Hi, thanks for the comment.  And thanks for the explanation of usage of !important.  But, the above did not reduce the height of my Footer :(

Comment: I just explained why; `.navbar.my-footer` will remain 20px high because of its inline style.

Comment: Sorry- I am a bit thick and very tired lol

Comment: What's the reason for the -1 please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use the developer tools to inspect the navbar, you will see that the bootstrap.css adds a min-height property which is set to 50px to the `.navbar` class.  As a result, if you want to set the height of the navbar to a value less than 50px, you'll have to override that style.

Add the following CSS (and ideally remove all of the inline styles):

```
.my-footer.navbar {
    min-height: 20px;
    height: 20px;
}
```

Comment: Hi, I did do that sometime ago. I forgot to close this question. But as great minds think the same